# MySQL cumulative sum produces the same value for multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I have this table:

| employee_id | experience | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Junior | 10000 |
| 9 | Junior | 15000 |
| 2 | Senior | 20000 |
| 11 | Senior | 16000 |
| 13 | Senior | 50000 |
| 4 | Junior | 40000 |

and I am trying to get the cumulative sum of salaries ordered by experience and salary.

My code:

```
SELECT employee_id, experience, salary, SUM(salary) OVER(ORDER BY experience, salary) as cumsum
FROM Candidates
```

Basically I want this output:

| employee_id | experience | salary | cumsum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Senior | 16000 | 16000 |
| 2 | Senior | 20000 | 36000 |
| 13 | Senior | 50000 | 86000 |
| 1 | Junior | 10000 | 96000 |
| 9 | Junior | 15000 | 111000 |
| 4 | Junior | 40000 | 151000 |

but I am getting this instead:

| employee_id | experience | salary | cumsum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Senior | 16000 | 16000 |
| 2 | Senior | 20000 | 36000 |
| 13 | Senior | 50000 | 151000 |
| 1 | Junior | 10000 | 151000 |
| 9 | Junior | 15000 | 151000 |
| 4 | Junior | 40000 | 151000 |

EDIT:
salary is unique.

This code works:

```
SELECT employee_id, experience, salary, SUM(salary) OVER(ORDER BY experience, salary ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as cumsum
FROM Candidates
```

Why does adding  `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as cumsum` make it work?

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/UCostfoq

Comment: Your query with this sample data cannot provide the output you suggest! Repeated values in a cumulative sum occur due to rows not having a deterministic order. If two rows have the same experience and salary you will see rows with the same cumulative sum value. You should add `id` to your `ORDER BY` to avoid this.

Comment: Your query have no PARTITION BY clause. So you may get the same cumulative sum for a lot of rows only when all rows with the same cum. sum have the same value for ORDER BY expression. I.e. shown query cannot produce shown output on shown source data.

Comment: How do you want to order the employee_id within the experience?

Comment: I should add that salary is unique. so Ordering by experience and salary, we wouldn't get any duplicate pairs. @user1191247

Comment: The frame definition you have added is the same as the default for an ordered partition, which suggests there is something else in play. Have you oversimplified your example and missed out a crucial detail?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT   employee_id
       , experience
       , salary
       , SUM(salary) OVER(ORDER BY experience, salary,employee_id) as cumsum
FROM Candidates
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the same result. Though the following code works: 
SELECT employee_id, experience, salary, SUM(salary) OVER(ORDER BY experience, salary ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as cumsum

I have no idea why this one works and not my original code.
FROM Candidates